# Angular Async Validator on multiple form fields

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-validation

I'm trying to implement an Async validator on a FormControl which relies on the value of another field of the same form.
To accomplish this same task in a Syncronous way, I would just create a validator function that I would attach to the FormGroup validators.

```
/**/
mySyncValidator(form: FormGroup): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    const field1 = form.get('field1').value;
    const field2 = form.get('field2').value;
    ...
};
```

Now, what should I do to accomplish the exact same thing in an Async way (basically calling a service performing an httpClient request) ?

All the examples provided in the Angular docs are relative to a single FormControl validation (afaik you cannot access other FormControls if you attach a validator to a single FormControl) https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the parent form of the control by using `parent` property, then get the control you want!

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UniqueAlterEgoValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private heroesService: HeroesService) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    const parent = control && control.parent;
    const anotherCtrl = parent.get('<insert-another-control-name>');
    return this.heroesService.isAlterEgoTaken(control.value, anotherCtrl.value).pipe(
      map(isTaken => (isTaken ? { uniqueAlterEgo: true } : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nite Does this answer solve your question?

Comment: Yes, I managed to code the validator. One thing to note is that we could use the same approach and attach the validator to the FormGroup. In that way you could just access the controls with 'control.get(...)'. Because in that case the control would be the form itself. Thank you !